# Взаимодействия классов на

Tags: c++, проектирование

Есть программа:
Пользователь выбирает зайца из 5 вариантов и выставляет на поле. На поле приходят волки и атакуют зайцев. Грубо говоря, как в Plants VS Zombie
Есть диаграмма классов. На ней нужно отобразить как взаимодействуют между собой волки и зайцы.
Про зайцев: их пять типов

1. Заяц дальнего боя - запускает снаряд в волка
2. Заяц ближнего боя - дерется с волком в ближнем бою (да неужели?)
3. Заяц-добытчик - время от времени добывает морковку (валюта для покупки зайцев)
4. Слабый защитник - выступает в роли слабой стены
5. Сильный защитник - выступает в роли сильной стены

Про волков: их четверо

1. Слабый воин
2. Средний воин
3. Сильный воин
4. Босс

На диаграмме видно, что все волки могут отличаться только скоростью и типом
Собственно проблема: не знаю какие связи нужно еще добавить на диаграмму, для взаимодействия волков и зайцев
[image: Диаграмма классов]

Comment: может, их уже достаточно, и пора код писать?

Comment: @strangeqargo в этом-то и проблема: сказали, что недостаточно

Comment: Уточните, чего именно ждёт принимающий.

Comment: @Monk хотят увидеть связи между волками и зайцами

Comment: Вам точно не нужны классы волков, если те отличаются только параметрами, но не функциями. Уберите их :)
Это то, что можно сказать по диаграмме классов. О каком взаимодействии волков и зайцев идет речь не ясно, т.ч. что добавлять тоже не ясно.
Может быть, методы в стиле `hit(TRabbit*)` у волка, и аналогичный у зайца? С возможностью по типу бьющего и его мишени определить уровень урона и выполнить его.

Comment: Вы просите помочь вам решить домашнее задание?